# Creating dispatcher timer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create a new dispatcher timer, with different periods each time method foo(30) is called using a timer value:

```
void foo(int timerValueInSeconds)
{
            TimeSpan _DestructionTimer = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timerValueInSeconds);
            DateTime _FullDestructionTimer = DateTime.Now + _DestructionTimer;

            DispatcherTimer _DispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _DispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            _DispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler((sender, e) => DispatcherTimer_Tick(sender, e, _FullDestructionTimer, _NewMessage, _DispatcherTimer));
            _DispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e, DateTime timer, Message _message, DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer)
{
    var remaining = timer - DateTime.Now;
    int remainingSeconds = (int)remaining.TotalSeconds;

    //update timer in view
    _message.Timer.ValueInSeconds = remainingSeconds;

    //stop the timer if reach to zero
    if (remaining.TotalSeconds <= 0)
    {
        _dispatcherTimer.Stop();

        //remove message from list 
    }
}
```

When I call foo(30) three times, I expect each timer should run in a different parallel thread, with its specified period, updating the view after each one is finished independently.

I call foo(30), then wait (for example) 3 seconds, then call foo(30) again. The timer is counting down depending on a previous count down timer value (which is 27s), and then it counts down with same value.

Comment: DispatcherTimer as it's name says runs on Dispatcher, thus all your timers will run on one thread - the same which is used by UI.

Comment: Probably a dumb question... but are both timers updating the same UI element (i.e. _NewMessage)?

Comment: it is not a dump question @Abhishek you should be a decent man

Comment: also this class System.Timers.Timer which should be work in different threads do the same behavior.